# invalid line type: must be length 2, 4, 6 or 8

Tags: r, plot

I am using segments for drawing line but i need little bit more control on line type. SO I am using lty="1" but i get error message.  I am using code below.

```
segments(593, 20.65+.06, 593+3, 20.65+.06, col= "black", lty="1")
```

But i am getting following error message.

```
  Error in segments(593, 20.65 + 0.06, 593 + 3, 20.65 + 0.06, col = "black",  : 
  invalid line type: must be length 2, 4, 6 or 8
```

I just need to control line type mentioned in lty().How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix it by reading `?par`:

> Line types can either be specified by giving an index into a small
>   built-in table of line types (1 = solid, 2 = dashed, etc, see lty
>   above) or directly as the lengths of on/off stretches of line. This is
>   done with a string of an even number (up to eight) of characters,
>   namely non-zero (hexadecimal) digits which give the lengths in
>   consecutive positions in the string. For example, the string "33"
>   specifies three units on followed by three off and "3313" specifies
>   three units on followed by three off followed by one on and finally
>   three off. The ‘units’ here are (on most devices) proportional to lwd,
>   and with lwd = 1 are in pixels or points or 1/96 inch.

So, passing a character to `lty` doesn't mean what you thought. You probably just meant `lty = 1`.

Answer (score 2):

I came here with the same error message, while defining lty for multiple (3) lines:

```
legend(..., lty = c(1, "dashed", "dotdash"), ...)
```

This error is solved by defining all linetypes with the respective string key:

```
legend(..., lty = c("solid", "dashed", "dotdash"), ...)
```